# Why doesnt my label refresh with newly entered data in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My goal was to refresh a label with its new contents on the click of a button, but when i click the button i get the error message below the code. I understand that it cant access the variable, but i dont understand why. How do i fix it and make the label update when i enter new text in the entry box and click the change button?

Main.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo # Message Box
from functions import *

root = tk.Tk()
current_title = Label(root, text=homepage.get_title())
current_title.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)   
def refresh_title_label():
            current_title.destroy()
            current_title = Label(root, text=homepage.get_title()) # this homepage.get_title() gets the text from a html file
            current_title.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

def change_title():
    
    x = new_title_input.get()
    homepage.change_title(x) # this changes the title in the html file
    refresh_title_label()
    showinfo('Title Changed')



new_title_label = Label(root, font='Helvetica 15', text='New Title: ' )
new_title_input = Entry(root, background='lightgrey', width=50 )

title_button = ttk.Button(root, text='Change', command=change_title)

new_title_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
new_title_input.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
title_button.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

functions.py:

```
# Importing the ssh connection
from ssh_config import *

# This is a class to change the index file
class homepage():
    
    # Gets the website title 
    def get_title():
        data = ssh_command('grep web_title index.html')
        data = data[26:]
        data = data[:-11]
        return data
    
    # changes website title
    def change_title(new_title):
        current_title = homepage.get_title()
        ssh_command(f"sed -i 's/{current_title}/{new_title}/g' index.html")
```

This is the error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\josep\Desktop\tkinter-ssh-backend\Untitled-1.py", line 20, in change_title
    refresh_title_label()
  File "c:\Users\josep\Desktop\tkinter-ssh-backend\Untitled-1.py", line 12, in refresh_title_label
    current_title.destroy()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'current_title' where it is not associated with a value
```

I tried making the variable global but that didnt work

```
root = tk.Tk()
global current_title
current_title = Label(root, text=homepage.get_title())
current_title.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
```

And i have tested to see if the ssh is working correctly and it is.

Comment: you are missing the global statement in your function, while having it in the global namespace is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

In main.py, you cannot put `current_title.destroy()` before `current_title = Label(root)`. You do this after `current_title.grip()`

- If you want to destroy Label(), you can't do simultaneous in the
  `refresh_title_label()` function.
- You can put `current_title.destroy()` in the `change_title()` function.
  It is up to you to suit your need.
- Add current_title.config in the `refresh_title_label()` function.

I am not using `ssh_config`. I can do workaround to show.

Snippet:

```
def refresh_title_label():
     current_title.config(text=new_title_input.get())
     current_title.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)

def change_title():    
    x = new_title_input.get()
    homepage.change_title(x) # this changes the title in the html file
    refresh_title_label()
    showinfo('Title Changed')
    current_title.destroy()

current_title = Label(root, text=homepage.get_title())
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot after clicking Change button:

[image]

Screenshot destroy the `Label`:

[image]